# pythonic way to try (repeatedly) to catch exceptions

Tags: python, exception, closures

I have a script that runs on an unattended machine.  If the script throws an error, I want to log the error and keep running as long as it's practical.  Here's my first draft of the code, but it doesn't work for reasons explained below.  (As a note: a more realistic `concede` function will return true if there are N errors captured within T seconds.  Or something.)

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def perseverance(concede = lambda: False):
    while (True):
        try:
            yield
        except Exception, e:
            if (concede()):
                log_exception(e, "conceding")
                raise
            else:
                log_exception(e, "retrying")
```

This would allow me to do something like:

```
def quit_after(n):
    n = [n]         # make n mutable for the closure :P
    def quitter():
        if (n[0] <= 0): return True
        n[0] -= 1
        return False
    return quitter

with perseverance(quit_after(3)):
    do_complex_script()
```

This doesn't work because the @contextmanager is fussy about exception handling.  This code will fail with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File ".../python2.7/contextlib.py", line 36, in __exit__
    raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop after throw()")
RuntimeError: generator didn't stop after throw()
```

I could trivially rewrite perseverance() to not use context manager but without its elegant syntax, like this:

```
def with_perseverance(fn, concede = lambda: False):
    while (True):
        try:
            fn()
        except Exception, e:
            if (concede()):
                log_exception(e, "conceding")
                raise
            else:
                log_exception(e, "retrying")
```

and call it like this:

```
with_perseverance(do_complex_script, quit_after(3))
```

### the question

At the risk of getting down-voted for being too subjective: Is there a better / more pythonic way to write this?

Comment: I'd be inclined to make `concede` an object of a certain class, and get the advantage of the class/object functionality, rather than trying to capture your state within the callable.

Comment: From the docs `If an exception is trapped merely in order to log it or to perform some action (rather than to suppress it entirely), the generator must reraise that exception` if i'm reading both this and your question correctly, this is causing your hangup

Comment: @user2085282 That error only says that the error must escape the function if you want the error to escape the `with`. That's not causing the `RuntimeError`, which is caused by having multiple `yield`s from the function.

Answer (score 1):

The `contextmanager` isn't fussy about exception handling; it just wants you to only `yield` once. Context managers don't support reentry.

If you want that, you have several options. One is to use a `with`-`for` combo:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

class MutableValue:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

@contextmanager
def null_context():
    yield

@contextmanager
def catch_and_log(mutable_return_successful):
    try:
        yield
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR:", e)
    else:
        mutable_return_successful.value = True

def quit_after(n):
    for _ in range(n-1):
        successful = MutableValue(False)
        yield catch_and_log(successful)
        if successful.value:
            return

    yield null_context()

for ctx in quit_after(5):
    with ctx:
        1/0

#>>> ERROR: division by zero
#>>> ERROR: division by zero
#>>> ERROR: division by zero
#>>> ERROR: division by zero
#>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>>>   File "", line 31, in <module>
#>>> ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Because the `with` needs to communicate with the `for`, I had to do a bit of hackery to get the returns right. It's still more readable than a class-based solution.

Another much easier option is to abuse decorators:

```
def quit_after(n):
    def inner(f):
        for _ in range(n-1):
            try:
                f()
            except Exception as e:
                print("ERROR:", e)
            else:
                return
        f()

    return inner

@quit_after(5)
def _():
    1/0
#>>> ERROR: division by zero
#>>> ERROR: division by zero
#>>> ERROR: division by zero
#>>> ERROR: division by zero
#>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>>>   File "", line 44, in <module>
#>>>   File "", line 40, in inner
#>>>   File "", line 46, in _
#>>> ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: The separation of the termination logic from the `catch_and_log` logic in @Veedrac's answer is an excellent idea.  Aside from that, though, the overall answer seems needlessly complex.

Comment: @fearless_fool The implementation is definitely a mess, but I think the resulting usage is OK with appropriate naming. The advantage to a context manager is that it doesn't introduce a new scope, and that matters quite a bit in 2.x.